# Ways to reduce loading time of wxPython GUI

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, wxpython

This question is a continuation of my question [Desktop GUI Loading Slow](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/144725/desktop-gui-loading-slow/145072#145072).

I have a desktop GUI developed in wxPython which uses sqlAlchemy for many record fetch queries from database. I am putting the fetched records in Python dictionaries and populating the GUI using that. But, since I am reading thousands of data in background, the GUI gets stuck and loads very slowly. Now the question is:

1. Should I create individual threads for each of the sqlalchemy data fetch queries? If the answer for this is yes, is the wx.callAfter() the method I have to focus on (for each query)? If someone give sample/untested code or link then it will be helpful.
2. Is there any other way to implement lazy loading in a desktop GUI ?

P.S.: Please note that this is first time I am doing multithreading and wxPython. I was earlier web developer on Python/Django. Also, I can't share codes due to restriction.

Comment: See [this](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/) article about multithreading in wxPython

Answer (score 2):

You should redesign your app so that data loading part and data display part are separate. Load data in a separate thread which should populate a DB Model in your app, use that Model to populate GUI, so when app loads GUI will load fast but will display 'loading...' or something like that at places where data has not loaded yet.

Another way to speedup things is don't run queries until they are needed e.g. wrap them in a class with get method, on get query DB, but all of it will depend on context.

Also if GUI is mostly for view then you can may be load a first set of small data and push other data to other views which user has to go thru some menu or tabs, that way you can delay loading until it is needed or load them in background.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to prevent your GUI from hanging. Of course you can do multi-threading and stuff the records in a global dictionary. But you'd probably run into the [global interpreter lock](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) (GIL), which would probably not help the reponsiveness of your GUI.

The first option is to use the event-driven nature of the GUI toolkit and use the "timeout" or "timer" functionality provided by the toolkit to call a function that loads a couple of records every time it is called. A [generator function](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) would work nicely for that. This is probably the easiest to implement. How many records you can load in one go depends on the speed of the machine. I would suggest to start with a single record, measure the loading of records, and increment the amount of record so that each invocation doesn't take longer than say 0.1 second.

Second is to use a second process for loading data, and then send it to the GUI in small chunks. Using a separate process (using the `multiprocessing` module) has the advantage that you cannot run into Python's GIL. Note that this is method more or less includes the first method, because you still have to process messages from the second process in the event loop of the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which widgets you use to load your data into, but if you use wx.grid.Grid or the ListCtrl, then yes, there are some "lazy" loading stuff in the virtual implementations of the respective widgets. See the wxPython demo for a grid that can hold a million cells, for example. Also see Anurag's answer. You really don't need to load all the data at once. Just load the data that you can actually display. Then you can load more when the user scrolls (or pre-load it in a background thread).